# Making a POST request with Chef

Tags: ruby, rest, curl, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to post a .json file to a server with a rest API with a Chef recipe, following [Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html) I came up with this code:

```
http_request '/tmp/bpp.json' do
  url 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/blueprints/bpp'
  headers ({
    'AUTHORIZATION' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64(user)}",
    'CONTENT-TYPE' => 'aplication/json'
    })
  action :post
end
```

For authorization token, `user` is a variable that contains `'user:password'`

When I run this chef recipe I obtain the following response:

```
Error executing action `post` on resource 'http_request[POST /tmp/bpp.json]'

Net::HTTPServerException
------------------------
400 "Bad Request"
```

Prior to this I was just executing a `curl` call and it was working fine, but I need to change to the `http_request` resource. This was the old (working) `curl` request:

```
curl --user user:password -H 'X-Requested-By:My-cookbook' --data @/tmp/bpp.json localhost:8080/api/v1/blueprints/bpp
```

I am not very used with REST apis and seems like an uncharted territory to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget about [`message`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html#examples). Using file name as resource name won't send this file as data. Try adding:

```
...
message lazy { IO.read('/tmp/bpp.json') }
...
```

In your case only the resource name - `/tmp/bpp.json`, will be sent. Not a file content. As stated in linked doc:

```
The message that is sent by the HTTP request. Default value: the name of the resource block See “Syntax” section above for more information.
```

Comment: Oh I see it clear now, instead of the file in the path `/tmp/bpp.json` what I have sent is the string `/tmp/bpp.json`

Is there an elegant/easy way to pass a file as message here? Should it be (by any means) loaded during the chef run in memory?

Comment: It depends, you can try to read file during chef run (File.read). but remember pure ruby code is [executed on compile phase](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/). So if you would like to put this file on server using chef, you would have to use lazy block. You can also put this file in data bag.

Comment: I made the example more specific.